# How to add $ sign over hoover on each employee

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-charting

I need to add `$` symbol over hoover   eg- 1000 --> `$1000`

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="BarChartController">
    <apex:chart height="400" width="400" data="{!employees}">
        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" fields="salary" title="Salary" minimum="0" maximum="5000">                
        </apex:axis>
        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="name" title="Name"/>
        <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="name" yField="salary"/>
    </apex:chart>

</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class BarChartController {
    public class Employee{
        public String name {get; set; }
        public Integer salary {get; set;}
        public String fsalary {get; set;}
        Employee(String name, Integer salary){
            this.name = name;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.fsalary = name+salary;
        }
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        List<Employee> lstEm = new List<Employee>();
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee1',1000));
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee2',2000));
        lstEm.add(new Employee('Employee3',3000));
        return lstEm;
    }
}
```

[image: Generated Chart]

Comment: If you have a new question, please read [ask] and then open a new post that fits our format expectations. Please don't edit your existing posts to make them into different questions. Thanks!

Comment: This question is not about `Apex`. It is about `Visualforce`. If you want to slightly adjust what you are asking here, then an [edit] makes sense. If you want to ask something completely different, you should instead post a distinct, separate `Question`.